# Get root view of one activity from another activity

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a root view of one activity from another lets say there are two activity A and B i want root view of activity A from B.please Help

Edit: I am Trying to make change in Main Activity from Preference Activity for ex i want to change the text of TextView in Main Activity as soon as i select a checkboxpreference from preference activity.

Comment: If you want to get layout of activity of A into B then AFAIK it's not possible. Every activity has it's own layout

Comment: This is not a good idea. Please explain **why** you think that activity B should have access to activity A's "root view". What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps we can give you a better solution for your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

A stopped, or hidden activity may no longer be present, to free up resources. It is not a good idea to reference objects from other Activities.

To send an event/data from one Activity to another Activity you may use:

1. Start newer activity using `startActivityForResult()`. And get results back via `onActivityResult()`.
2. Share some data is a third object, accessible to all activities. Most likely a singleton or Application class.
3. Use `EventBus` and post `sticky` events. New subscribers will automatically get these events. This method works for all kinds of objects, not just activities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you would need this for, it sounds a little dangerous, but the root view *probably* won't exist without running first, but you MAY be able to get the root view while it's running and pass it to Activity B, but the view shouldn't be active while it's not running, thus will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Create it as static and pass the rootView to it on OnCreate, or pass it to the Application class so it persist between entire application. Verify if its null before doing operations.

I never tryed it, but my guess is that while activity is not finished the rootView can be accesed (its status stays on pause while another activity is active).

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are trying to trigger an action across activities when your preference changed. I suggest to use [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send the message from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA`. I assume that your `ActivityB` is the preference and active activity, and `ActivityA` is in the back stack:

**ActivityB.java**

```
mListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // create your broadcast intent and pass the value of changed preference
        Intent intent = ...
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
};
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
```

**ActivityA.java**

```
mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // handle your change to ActivityA here
    }
};
// create intent filter for your preference change broadcast
IntentFilter intentFilter = ...
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Given that your `ActivityA` is not yet destroyed, it will be able to catch the broadcast and you can achieve what you want.